# Get.Edgelist from R matrix when rownames and column names don't match

Tags: r, matrix, graph, igraph, adjacency-list

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
                  Abdominal pain Chest pain Flu-like Liver Damage Nausea Numbness Swelling
       Avandaia                  1          0        0            1      1        1        1
       Warfrin                   0          1        1            0      1        1        1
       Flu-like                  0          0        0            0      0        0        0
       Liver Damage              0          0        0            0      0        0        0
       Nausea                    0          0        0            0      0        0        0
       Numbness                  0          0        0            0      0        0        0
       Swelling                  0          0        0            0      0        0        0
```

I want to get the edgelist that looks like this:

```
Abdominal Pain | Avandaia
Chest Pain     | Warfrin
Flu-Like       | Warfrin
Liver Damage   | Avandaia
Nausea         | Avanadia
Nausea         | Warfrin
....
....
```

I've used R's igraph package before to get.edgelist with an adjacency matrix, but I believe in that case the rownames and column names must match. How can I do it with a dataframe like this where there are different row and column names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

some solutions without using `igraph`

```
df <- read.csv(text="Drug,Abdominal pain,Chest pain,Flu-like,Liver Damage,Nausea,Numbness,Swelling
Avandaia,1,0,0,1,1,1,1
Warfrin,0,1,1,0,1,1,1
Flu-like,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Liver Damage,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Nausea,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Numbness,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Swelling,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
", check.names=FALSE)


library(tidyr)
gather_(df, "Symptom", "Count", setdiff(names(df),"Drug")) %>% 
    filter(Count > 0)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
melt.data.table(df, measure.vars=setdiff(names(df),"Drug"))[value>0]
```